# Setting ListView Background

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I hope to set the background with different brush, however, it doesn't work. No error, No warnings.

In my code, I hope make rows in ListView have different backgrounds, So, I define a Style for ListViewItem, but it can't know now. While I debug the code, I could step into local:NumberConverter:Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture), however, the backgrounds of rows keep its original colors.

```
<UserControl x:Class="demo05_wpf02_binding.TabControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:demo05_wpf02_binding"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BookListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProfitBrush" StartPoint="0.2,0" EndPoint="0.8,1">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="LavenderBlush" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="CornflowerBlue" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LossBrush" StartPoint="0.2,0" EndPoint="0.8,1">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="LightYellow" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <local:NumberConverter x:Key="numConverter" />
            </Style.Resources>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource numConverter}}" Value="0" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProfitBrush}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource numConverter}}" Value="1" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LossBrush}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ListView Name="ListView01" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BookListStyle}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Margin="5">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Publisher" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ISBN" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ISBN}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: *Output* should show you more info.

Comment: `Title` will not be in your `DataContext` of `ListView`... So `Title` Change notification not sent to the Binding and the Converter wont try to convert.

Comment: @Sankarann, logically you would think that was true... but it's not. The properties of the data type instance *inside* the `ListBoxItem` *can* be accessed in a `Style` for the `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: What's the output do you want? Compiling output or UI output? @AnatoliiGabuza

Answer (score 0):

Your problem *must* lie in your `Converter`. If you removed the `Converter`, then your XAML would work just fine as it is *if your data items had `Title` values of `1` and `0`*.

```
<Style x:Key="BookListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProfitBrush" StartPoint="0.2,0" EndPoint="0.8,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="LavenderBlush" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="CornflowerBlue" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LossBrush" StartPoint="0.2,0" EndPoint="0.8,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="LightYellow" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Style.Resources>            
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}" Value="0" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProfitBrush}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}" Value="1" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LossBrush}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>            
</Style>
```

So look closely at the code in your `Converter`... put a breakpoint there and step through the code until you find your problem. One other thing to note is that your `LossBrush` is very hard to see... maybe a stronger colour would help, even if only used when testing.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, maybe I need to review my code again. And, I agree with you that LossBrush is a bad color. I need a new one. @Sheridan